# How to restrict access to admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a frontend and admin section. there are 3roles super_admin,admin,user. When logged in with super_admin or admin i should be able to access /admin/ namespace, which is working. But when I am logged in as user, i should not be able to access /admin/ namespace, it should redirect 404page or index page. I am using cancan to restrict access of controllers.

```
namespace :admin do
// admin routes
end

//Devise for user model
devise_for :users

//Role model
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users 
end

//User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :role
end

//Role table columns
id name
1  super_admin
2  admin
3  user
```

When I am logged in with user role and go to /admin/ path, it redirects to admin section. How do i restrict it in routes only for user role?

Comment: can u please post devise_for section of your routes file

Comment: I have posted. Thanks

Comment: please provide roles table column names with one record

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Add base controller for admin namespace
   admin/base_controller.rb

   ```
   class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :restrict_user_by_role

     # edit valid roles here      
     VALID_ROLES = ['super_admin', 'admin']

   protected

     # redirect if user not logged in or does not have a valid role
     def restrict_user_by_role
       unless current_user && VALID_ROLES.include?(current_user.role)
         redirect_to root_path # change this to your 404 page if needed
       end
     end

   end
   ```
2. Inherit all controllers in admin namespace from Admin::BaseController

admin/home_controller.rb

```
class Admin::HomeController < Admin::BaseController

  def index
  end

end
```

Comment: how do we write spec for restrict_user_by_role?